# Unable to deploy my project on Tomcat 8 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat

Does someone knows what is going on with my project. The Tomcat by itself is running fine, however when I try to run my project it keeps crashing. I get the following error:

```
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Visminer' did not find a matching property.
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.36.0
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.4.0-34-generic
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/rafael/Documents/Eclipse Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/rafael/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/rafael/Documents/Eclipse Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/rafael/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/rafael/Documents/Eclipse Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/rafael/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/endorsed
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 397 ms
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
ago 19, 2016 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/visminer-dashboard]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/visminer-dashboard]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7243ce3d]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5088)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@68b031d7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 13 more

ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8006]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more

ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
ago 19, 2016 2:37:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Is that a problem with the dependencies, with maven, with the server ? I really don't know what could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on your project in the Project Explorer
2. Choose 'Build Path' > 'Configure Build Path'
3. In the Libraries tab, click 'Add Library'
4. Choose 'Server Runtime' and click next
5. Select the 'Apache Tomcat v8.0' runtime and click finish
6. Go to the 'Order and Export' tab
7. Click 'Select All' (or whatever you need for your project)
8. Click 'Apply and Close'

Eclipse will build the project, which can take a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to fact that both web.xml is used for servlet mapping as well as annotations are used in the servlet class. If you are using tomcat 8.0 try commenting annotation in the servlet class this should help resolving the error which worked for me